# Seaborn Bargraph Ascending order

Tags: python, seaborn

Hello I have the following code which gives me the following output[image: Bar graph of average loan amount based on state]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,18))
sns.barplot(x='addr_state', y = 'loan_amnt', data=data, ci= None, estimator=mean)
plt.xlabel("State", size=15)
plt.ylabel("Average Loan Amount", size=15)
plt.tight_layout()
```

I am trying to make the order descending but whenever I run the code I keep getting an error but I remove order = descending it runs but it is not in order. I am trying to sort it by the average amount per state. Also is there a way to make the state text larger as well as the loan amounts. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Seaborn hasn't a built-in way to order via the aggregated amounts.
Pandas, however, can create such an aggregated and sorted list which then can be plotted via Seaborn.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 200
data = pd.DataFrame({'addr_state': np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrst'), N),
                     'loan_amnt': np.random.uniform(1000, 10000, N)})
agg_data = data.groupby('addr_state').aggregate('mean').sort_values('loan_amnt', ascending=False)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
sns.barplot(x=agg_data.index, y='loan_amnt', data=agg_data)
plt.xlabel("State", size=15)
plt.ylabel("Average Loan Amount", size=15)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

To include the lines indicating the confidence intervals, the barplot could be created from the original data, using the order of the sorted aggregated data:

```py
sns.barplot(x='addr_state', y='loan_amnt', order=agg_data.index, data=data)
```

[image: ordered sns.barplot including confidence intervals]